# which type noise in thresholding paper

Tags: c++, opencv, noise

I haven't worked with OpenCV before. I try to denoise music sheet paper. Firstly, I change color of paper as gray and then I apply tresholding function for this paper. However some black points exist in paper.Are these noise? How do I destroy these black points ?

[image: thresholding image]

Answer (score -1):

You can you contour thresholding using cv::findcontour and cv::contourArea in opencv

Comment: findContour() and contourArea() may help you decide which contours are noisy, based on their area, but they won't help you remove them

Comment: I have done such before and it works. What you mean it wont help you remove them? it just simple thresholding